# Azure pipeline - Use artifact from pull request build pipeline (PR automated) in a build pipeline (Batched CI)

Tags: azure, devops, pipeline

In Azure DevOps we have a branch policy so that when you create a pull request, a "pr-build" pipeline runs (PR automated) and in this pipeline it builds the solution, runs all the tests and publishes the built files as an artifact.

Once this pull request has been reviewed and is merged into our main branch it then fires a new pipeline "main-build" (Batched CI), which builds the solution again and deploys to a CD environment.

What I would like to do is instead of building the solution again, somehow get the artifact from the "pr-build" pipeline.

Is this possible?